# How to remove duplicates from struct array in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have data in text file. It's only name and points. I need to remove duplicate names and count the average of points. I created a struct and read the file into struct array. Now how can I manipulate data in array? How can I take persons, who is in file more than one time, points and calculate average? Perl is new language for me and I don't know syntax well. My code:

```
use Class::Struct; 
use warnings;
use strict;   

struct Person => {
    name => '$',
    points => '$'};


my $filename = 'data.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
    or die "Could not open file\n";

my @resultArray;
my @name;
my @name2;
my @grade2;
my @grade;
my @nameArray;
my @gradeArray;

my $person = Person->new();


while (my $row = <$fh>) {
    chomp $row;
    (@name, @grade) = split("\t", $row);
    push(@nameArray, @name);
    #($person->name, $person->points) = split("\t", $row);  
    #push(@nameArray, @name);

}
foreach(@nameArray) {
my @seperated = split(' ', $_);
$person->name($seperated[0]);
$person->points($seperated[1]);
}

print($person->points);
```

Comment: `(@name, @grade) = split("\t", $row);` is wrong, you can't assign to two arrays at the same time - the first one takes all the elements of the RHS.

Comment: Please show some of that data file

Comment: @zdim data file looks this but in seperate lines. In one line there is only one name and points:
John 5 
Smith 8
Mae 4
Walker 9

Comment: Then the code with arrays makes no sense (on top of being wrong as @choroba noted) since the split returns exactly two strings, right for `($name, $points)` scalars.  The data should be specifed in the question and I'd suggest that you edit it and add that.

Comment: Re: "_I need to remove duplicate names and count the average of points._" -- do you mean to find average points for all entries for a duplicated name and produce one entry for that name with those points?

Comment: @zdim Yes. I need to count the average points for every person. But the person can be written in file several times. So I just need to count average of points and produce only one entry for that name with points

Comment: @zdim's " $people{$name} += $pts;" would be my call here too for obtaining the average. Its a very cool trick. I sit on exam boards and logical errors in this code would be fun :-)

Comment: @MichaelG. Yes, I can imagine all sorts of things :) This can be useful to hammer out basics -- it is elementary but it contains some picky low-level counting and logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have an array entry for each person you need to create a new object for each, inside the loop. Once you've read the data you'd have to post-process that to establish duplicates and remove all but one entry.

That is inefficient, with extra calls to constructor and destructor, and deletions from an array.

Thus I'd suggest to read data into a hash instead, in which way you can also process duplicates as you go. Then populate an array with `struct` objects for further work.

```
use warnings;
use strict;   
use feature 'say';

use Class::Struct; 

struct Person => { name => '$', points => '$' };

my @people; 

PREPARE_DATA: {    
    my (%people, %cnt);

    while (<DATA>) {
        my ($name, $pts) = split;
        if (exists $people{$name}) {
            $people{$name} += $pts;
            ++$cnt{$name};
        }   
        else { 
            $people{$name} = $pts;
        }   
    }

    foreach my $name (keys %cnt) { 
        $people{$name} /= $cnt{$name}+1;
    }    

    # Now populate an array with objects
    foreach my $name (sort keys %people) {    
        push @people, Person->new(name => $name, points => $people{$name});
    }
};

for my $p (@people) {
    say $p->name, ' --> ', $p->points;
}

__DATA__
Joe 12
John 20
Joe 24
John 40
Joe 36
Matt 15
```

I put all processing in a block (which I named `PREPARE_DATA`) to limit the scope of the ancillary variables used; after the block only the desired `@people` exists.

The data is supplied using the `__DATA__` section, so that all data used here is readily seen.

The test for existence, whereby the count of only dupes is kept, is not necessary. One can add points and increase the count for each person, and later divide all by their counts. Checking only dupes is a little more efficient and, more importantly, lends itself more readily to checking other kinds of properties.

Comment: @GR2096  Edited, as I forgot to include data after `__DATA__` and the printout of results